# Typo3 10.4 specific actions on pages

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I haven't found anyone asking this question yet although it seems like this should be a more commonly asked question.

Is there a way of selecting which action a plugin should use depending on the page?
If I go to example.com/news then the news plugin should use the listAction but if I go to example.com/clear the news plugin should be using the deleteAllAction. Is there a way to accomplish this? Or rather is there an easier way than using extbase routeEnhancers?
I guess the easiest way would be to register a new plugin with a different action but the same base.

Comment: I suppose could make both trigger an initial "choser" action - and then inside there, get the page id, and _forward_ to either the list or delete action.

Comment: Earlier this was done via switchableControllerActions, but from v10 you need to create a separate plugin with the wanted action.